# Number of Activity Diagrams

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, staruml

I just started out with UML and I was wondering should my UML model have multiple activity diagrams?
Each diagram would be for a specific use case.
I am using StarUML for the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, anything but the most trivial system would require more than one Activity Diagram to model it's behavior.

One Activity (with owned Activity Diagram) per Use Case is pretty what I would expect.